# tf.io.read_file unable to find file or directory from a numpy array

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

For tensor flow data base loading, I saved a numpy array from my database.

```
images= train_dataset[i]
image_string = tf.io.read_file(images)
```

This is a part of my training function. And it seems to be failing.

The issue is

```
(iP6)21.jpg; No such file or directory
```

Any help appreciated.

Edited to explain the whole code:

train_dataset is a variable to hold a numpy file.

```
train_dataset=X_train_shuffled
```

for the sake of completeness, here is the entire training function

```
'training'
import time
import tensorflow as tf
#from tensorflow import read_file
def train():
    data=filenames_shuffled
    data
    info=y_labels_one_hot_shuffled
    #data, info = tfds.load("mnist", with_info=True, data_dir='/data/tensorflow_datasets')
    #train_data = data['train']
    train_data=X_train_filenames

    if not os.path.exists('./images'):
        os.makedirs('./images')

    # settting hyperparameter
    latent_dim = 100
    epochs = 800
    batch_size = 32
    buffer_size = 6000
    save_interval = 50

    img_shape = (32, 32, 3)

    #num_classes = info.features['label'].num_classes
    #num_classes=10
    num_classes=y_train
    generator = Generator(num_classes)
    discriminator = Discriminator(num_classes)

    gen_optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.0002, 0.5)
    disc_optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.0002, 0.5)

    #train_dataset = train_data.map(lambda x: preprocess_image(x, img_shape, num_classes)).shuffle(buffer_size).batch(batch_size)
    train_dataset=train_data
    cross_entropy = tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True)

    @tf.function
    def train_step(images, labels):
        noise = tf.random.normal([batch_size, latent_dim])

        with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as tape:
            generated_images = generator(noise, labels)

            real_output = discriminator(images, labels)
            generated_output = discriminator(generated_images, labels)

            gen_loss = generator_loss(cross_entropy, generated_output)
            disc_loss = discriminator_loss(cross_entropy, real_output, generated_output)

        grad_gen = tape.gradient(gen_loss, generator.trainable_variables)
        grad_disc = tape.gradient(disc_loss, discriminator.trainable_variables)

        gen_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grad_gen, generator.trainable_variables))
        disc_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grad_disc, discriminator.trainable_variables))

        return gen_loss, disc_loss

    seed = tf.random.normal([16, latent_dim])
    #train_dataset.append(y_train)
    #train_dataset=np.append(train_dataset,y_train)
    for epoch in range(1, epochs + 1):
        start = time.time()
        total_gen_loss = 0
        total_disc_loss = 0
        #for images in filenames_shuffled and labels in y_labels_one_hot_shuffled:
        '''
        Trying an alternate for loop thing. As your numpy cannot be called
        for images,labels in train_dataset():
            gen_loss, disc_loss = train_step(images, labels)

            total_gen_loss += gen_loss
            total_disc_loss += disc_loss
        '''
        i=0
        #print(train_dataset)
        #print("done")
        #print(y_train)
        while i<2200:
          images= train_dataset[i]
          labels=y_train[i]
          '''
          added this region. Not sure what is happening
          Input filename tensor must be scalar, but had shape: [2200] [Op:ReadFile]
          '''

          image_string = tf.io.read_file(images)
          image_decoded = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image_string, channels=3)
          images = tf.cast(image_decoded, tf.float32)
          '''
          till here
          '''
          #filenames_shuffled_numpy, y_labels_one_hot_shuffled
          #print("No error")
          gen_loss, disc_loss = train_step(images, labels)
          #print("error")
          total_gen_loss += gen_loss
          total_disc_loss += disc_loss
          i=i+1
        print('Time for epoch {} is {} sec - gen_loss = {}, disc_loss = {}'.format(epoch, time.time() - start, total_gen_loss / batch_size, total_disc_loss / batch_size))
        if epoch % save_interval == 0:
            save_imgs(epoch, generator, seed)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    train()
```

If you need more information, I will happily provide it

Comment: Be sure to have those files in the main path of your project. You are physically missing the file "21.jpg" in the folder of your project. That's it.

Comment: I am currently working with collab. I have my dataset in collab and everything seems to work fine. It doesn't let me take my training dataset folder into collab. Maybe I will have to work everything into drive. Thank you for the advice. Will be trying it out now

Comment: UPDATE: I have everything stored in the same folder(My dataset and my numpys) both in drive. I change directory to access it as well. But when I do abc=filenames or filenames.npy     I don't get the step working

Comment: Can you upload the whole code? Might be easier to suggest you the right way, just edit the initial question.

Comment: Sure thing. I just made the changes

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60238349/datatype-conversion-in-tensorflow-python  this error represents the difference between expected and actual datatype being fed @JohnCalchon